# access 2010 listbox OLE field

Tags: listbox, ms-access-2010

I have a simple query showing serial numbers and a machine type for a simple searchable function within a form. this query also contains an OLE column whih contains customer gathered data from a machine (parameters and alarm histories etc). I want the OLE section to be included within the list box so when the machine is searched for, the searcher will have access to all of the data for that machine.

is there an 'on click' or 'on enter' command for this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You put the recordID, along with the serial number and machine type in the query for the list box. then when the listbox selection is made, the event can trigger filling in the OLE field on the form - by using the recordID of the selected item.

All that being said - it's a huge guess as to even what you're talking about because you haven't shown us any form or table design or query.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it has been decided that the project im working on should now be focused around sharepoint and no longer access.